# Error while installing and updating SDWebImage with pod file

Tags: cocoapods, sdwebimage, ios9.1

When try to install pod file two components return error in terminal.
I am using Objective-c and iOS9.
please help me.

**podfile:**

pod 'DZNPhotoPickerController', '~> 1.6'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'

**Errors in terminal:**

pod install

Updating local specs repositories

Analyzing dependencies

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `SDWebImage (~> 3.7)` required by `Podfile`
- `SDWebImage (= 3.7.3)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `SDWebImage (= 3.7)` required by `DZNPhotoPickerController/Core (1.6.0)`

Answer (score 3):

Reza Jan,
you can delete `Podfile.lock` and try `pod install` again. It will help with your second line of error. and remove `pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'` because it will be added as a dependency of `DZNPhotoPickerController` anyway.

Cheers

Comment: You can delete `Pods` folder for all that matters and nothing will happen. I hope you haven't modified any pods inside your project. Delete `Pods` folder and run `pod install` again.